# Optional text on Symfony router

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.3

I'm trying something with the Symfony router but I cannot achieve what I'm aiming to.

Indeed I want to add an optional text to this path, especially for the `/page-{page}`. So I'm asking if it's possible to have two possibilities for the same router path, like the following ones:

- /topic/{id}
- /topic/{id}/page-{page}

routing.yml:

```
utm_forum_forum:
    path:     /forum/{id}/page-{page}
    defaults:
        _controller: UTMForumBundle:Forum:forum
        page: 1
    requirements:
        id: \d+
        page: \d+
```

Thanks for reading, and if I'm not clear enough I can re-explain :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include routes for all possible configurations.

So, if your page slug is optional, your route table should look something like:

```
utm_forum_forum_default:
    path:     /forum/{id}
    defaults:
        _controller: UTMForumBundle:Forum:forum
        page: 1
    requirements:
        id: \d+

utm_forum_forum:
    path:     /forum/{id}/page-{page}
    defaults:
        _controller: UTMForumBundle:Forum:forum
    requirements:
        id: \d+
        page: \d+
```

That should provide a default value of page 1 when the page slug is omitted entirely, or require something in the form `page-N` after the ID.

Comment: Thank you really much for your help, I had thought of this solution but I wasn't really shure of the viability.

Answer (score 0):

```
utm_forum_forum:
    path:     /forum/{id}/page-{page}
    defaults: { _controller: UTMForumBundle:Forum:forum, page: null }
```

so if you request for /forum/15/page- will give you null in {page} parameter.

Don't know if its what you need

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I already define a default value for the page parameter, the problem is not there, I want to make the 'page-' optionnal in order to get clean links without page number.

Comment: Then you could create two routings, one with 'page-' and another without it, both pointing at same controller and setting default 'page' value to null on one without 'page-' on url.